# How can I inspect memory usage per package in a large node application?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, node-modules

I'm using a large node application that takes up to 250MB of memory under heavy usage. The application, [theia-ide](https://theia-ide.org), has a pluggable architecture and is made up of a large number of packages. I would like to find out which packages are causing the most memory usage, similar to how I might use a disk usage analyzer to drill-down and see what folders are using the most space. What is the best way go about this?